# i want to group by both coulmn result where like condition fulfilled?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM ks_fund_transaction 
where  (from_fund  like '%COIN%' or to_fund  like '%COIN%')  
GROUP BY from_fund;
```

here you can fing result
http://prntscr.com/1ze745i

```
id  fund_type   from_fund   to_fund amount  t_date  dt  update_date emp_id
55  Withdrawal  COIN SWITCH KUBER   KJSB    100 2021-11-13  2021-11-13  2021-11-13  415
54  Deposite    KJSB    COIN SWITCH KUBER   10000   2021-11-13  2021-11-13  2021-11-13  415
56  Withdrawal  KJSB1   COIN SWITCH KUBER   100 2021-11-13  2021-11-13  2021-11-13  415
```

only one time COIN SWITCH KUBER will get

Comment: What is the logic for determining which of these 2 records gets retained?

Answer (score 0):

Use a conditional in `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY IF(from_fund LIKE '%COIN%', from_fund, to_fund)
```